# Finding maximum value of the four neighbours in 2D arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

I want to find the maximum value of the four neighbours of items in 2D numpy array. The first solution I came up was using `scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

a = np.random.uniform(low=10, high=100, size=(6500,6500)).astype(np.float)

def filter2d(footprint_elements):
    return max(footprint_elements)

footprint = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                       [1, 0, 1],
                       [0, 1, 0]])

maxs = scipy.ndimage.generic_filter(a,filter2d, footprint=footprint)
```

The problem with using generic filter here is that it is very slow, so I came up with a faster solution (Please note that edges are not important):

```
maxs = np.maximum.reduce([a[:-2, 1:-1], a[1:-1, 2:], a[2:, 1:-1], a[1:-1,:-2]])
```

I'm looking for any method that might be faster.

I'm not sure if considering this might gain speed but I'm only interested only in specific items (which are determined by another array). For example find the maximum neighbour of those items in array `a` where array `b` is bigger than `0`:

```
b = np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10, size=(6500,6500)).astype(np.float)

# need to find maximum neighbour of array a where b > 0

 maxs[b > 0]
```

Comment: FYI: `np.random.uniform()` returns an array of floating point values, so there is no need to use `astype(np.float)` afterwards.

Comment: Compiling your filter2d fuction to a c-callback function may also worth a try. Take a look at the following example: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.36.1/user/cfunc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`, you can use [`scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter.html).  It also accepts a `footprint` argument:

```
from scipy.ndimage import maximum_filter

maxs = maximum_filter(a, footprint=footprint)
```

Timing:

```
In [105]: a = np.random.uniform(low=10, high=100, size=(6500,6500))

In [106]: %timeit maxs = maximum_filter(a, footprint=footprint)
858 ms ± 2.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [107]: %timeit maxs = np.maximum.reduce([a[:-2, 1:-1], a[1:-1, 2:], a[2:, 1:-1], a[1:-1,:-2]])
1.34 s ± 12.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So `maximum_filter` is a bit faster than using `np.maximum.reduce` applied to the slices.